# Bulb planting depth

Tags: planting, bulbs

I'm starting my fall planting and got to wondering - is the recommended planting depth to the top or bottom of the bulb?

Answer (score 5):

If it says plant 4 inches deep on the packet, plant it  in a hole that deep; the measurement listed applies to the depth of the hole.  There is a general rule for bulb planting, which is, plant as deep as 2-3 times the height of the bulb, which means that daffodils, for instance, are likely to be six inches deep, whereas smaller bulbs will be 3 or 4 inches deep.